# Поведение istringstream c++ и его альтернатива

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

Есть функция **hexstr_to_str** читающая из *памяти(не файл, не cin)* поток текста вида "01 03 10 fa", и записывающая в std::string содержащую \x01\x03\x10\xfa. Проблема с чтением из потока целых чисел заключается в том, что *после чтения последнего числа* устанавливается флаг в потоке **failbit**. Есть ли альтернатива istringstream, или после чтения каждого числа из потока необходимо делать проверку на конец строки, например, через peek()? Есть ли решения проще?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

ssize_t hexstr_to_str(std::string &destination, std::istringstream &stream_source)
{
    std::ios::fmtflags 
              old_flags = stream_source.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);
    size_t    count     = 0;
    int       symbol    = -1;
    destination.clear();
    while ( stream_source >> symbol ) //добавление  && !stream_source.eof() результата не дало. 
    {
        destination += symbol;
        ++count;
    }
    stream_source.setf(old_flags);
    std::cout << (stream_source.rdstate() & (stream_source.failbit | stream_source.badbit))<<"\n";
    return  !(stream_source.rdstate() & (stream_source.failbit | stream_source.badbit)) ? count : -count;
}



int main()
{
    std::string hb_str;
    //std::cout << hexstr_to_str(hello_str, std::istringstream(cstr_hex_hello));
    hexstr_to_str(hb_str, std::istringstream("10 20 af 30"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем вообще stream'ы, если буфер в памяти вашего формата легко разбирается через доступ к этом самой памяти через str[i]?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов буфер в текстовом формате хранится. string a = "10 20 af 30";  str[0] = 1 в таком случае. Мне необходимо 0x10. Или вы имели ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: stream_source >> std::hex  должен помочь

Comment: @Chorkov увы, но всё тоже самое.

Comment: @borat_brata именно это я и имел в виду. stream'ы не нужны, даже никакие библиотечные функции не нужны для решения задачи.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов пример можно.

Comment: @borat_brata ну например num[i] = ((str[i * 3] - 0x30) <<4) + ((str[i * 3 + 1] - 0x30)) для случая, если там нет букв a-f. Для учета букв делается таблица преобразования и вместо str[...] пишется table[str[...]] в вышеприведенной формуле. Стримы не нужны, а завершение буфера определяется так: str[i * 3] == 0
PS. Если таблица, то "-0x30" не нужно.

Comment: Держитесь в рамках уважительного общения. Вы второй день бьётесь над какой-то странной задачей (судя по истории ваших вопросов), которую не можете толком сформулировать. Какие вопросы вы задаёте, такие ответы и получаете.

Comment: @user1056837 я вроде не оскорбил никого. Но прошу прощения всё-равно. бьюсь в свободное время. А задача в том, что из набора текстовых шестнадцатеричных значений, разделенных пробелом получить их числовой код и записать в строку и именно на с++.

Comment: @user1056837 да все он нормально сформулировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему наличие `failbit` вы считаете проблемой?

Забудьте про него, это нормальное поведение в конце строки.

Проверяйте `eof` - если конец строки достигнут, то разбор строки был успешен. Если не достигнут - значит, была ошибка:

```
return stream_source.eof() ? count : -count;
```

Comment: Проблемой считаю из документации. Выставился флаг- значит плохо. Но пожалуй Вы правы eof помогает.

Comment: @borat_brata, кресты вообще бредовый язык

Comment: @avp на первый взгляд мне чистый си больше понравился, но пытаюсь их параллельно изучать. В плюсах код писать побыстрее как-то.

Comment: @borat_brata, imho Вы абсолютно правы, а поскольку многие пишут на С++, то познания в нем  все равно будут нужны.

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай (развлекся)

```
using namespace std;

string get_xstr (string str, long *errpos) {
  if (errpos)
    *errpos = -1;
  istringstream istr(str);
  ostringstream ostr;
  long x, curpos;
  istr.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);
  ostr.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);

  while (istr >> x) {
    curpos = istr.tellg();
    ostr << "\\x" << x;
  }
  if (!istr.eof() && errpos) 
    *errpos = curpos;

  return ostr.str();
}
```

Обратите внимание, возможную позицию ошибки в строке приходится брать в цикле, поскольку поведение `.tellg()` аналогично бреду с `failbit`.